# How to use simple way find text between Strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

everyone
i want to ask have any simple way / function to findout "IWantThisText" in Alltext

```
var Alltext = "variableStringA + anchorString1 + IWantThisText + anchorString2 + variableStringB"
var StartString = "anchorString1+"
var EndString = "+anchorString2"
```

I want result = "IWantThisText"

Comment: `Alltext.replace(StartString, "").replace(EndString, "")`
Will work for you, but I doubt that this question belongs to stackoverflow.

Comment: considering anchorstring 1,2 is variable long string, and running speed , i want to know new way which better than normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var Alltext = "String1+IWantThisText+String2"
const m = Alltext.match(/String1\+(.*)\+String2/);
console.info(m[1]);
```